# Error serializing `.product` returned from `getStaticProps` | using NextJS and Stripe

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, next.js, serialization

I encountered the following error "Error: Error serializing .product returned from getStaticProps in "/products/[id]".
Reason: undefined cannot be serialized as JSON. Please use null or omit this value."

This happened when I tried creating individual product pages for my e-commerce website.

My code in "/products/[id]"

```
import Image from "next/image";
import { stripe } from "src/utils/stripe";
import { CheckIcon, MinusSmallIcon, PlusSmallIcon } from "@heroicons/react/24/solid"
import { formatCurrencyString, useShoppingCart } from "use-shopping-cart";
import { useState } from "react";
import { toast } from "react-hot-toast";

export default function ProductPage({ product }) {
    const [count, setCount] =  useState(1);
    const { addItem } = useShoppingCart()

    function onAddToCart(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const id = toast.loading("Adding 1 item...");
        addItem(product);
        toast.success(product.name, { id });
    }


    return (
        <div className="container lg:max-w-screen-lg mx-auto py-12 px-6">
            <div className="flex flex-col md:flex-row justify-between items-center space-y-8 md:space-y-0 md:space-x-12">
                <div className="relatie w-72 h-72 sm:w-96 sm:h-96">
                    <Image src={product.image} alt={product.name} fill style={{objectFit: "contain" }} sizes="100%" priority />
                </div>

                <div className="w-full flex-1 max-w-md border border-opacity-50 rounded-md shadow-lg p-6 bg-whitie">
                    <h2 className="text-3x1 font-semibold">{product.name}</h2>
                    <p className="pt-2 flex items-center space-x-2">
                        <CheckIcon className="text-lime-500 w-5 h-5" />
                        <span className="font-semibold">In stock</span>
                    </p>

                    <div className="mt-4 border-t pt-4">
                        <p className="text-gray-500">Price: </p>
                        <p className="text-xl front-semibold">{formatCurrencyString({ value: product.price, currency: product.currency,})} </p>
                    </div>

                    <div className="mt-4 border-t pt-4">
                        <p className="text-gray-500">Quantity</p>
                        <div className="mt-1 flex items-center space-x-3">
                            <button disabled={count <= 1} onClick={() => setCount(count - 1)} className="p-1 rounded-md hover:bg-rose-100 hover:text-rose-500">
                                <MinusSmallIcon className="w-6 h-6 flex-shrink-0"/>
                            </button>
                            <p className="font-semibold text-xl">{count}</p>
                            <button onAbort={() => setCount(count + 1)} className="p-1 rounded-md hover:bg-green-100 hover:text-green-500">
                                <PlusSmallIcon className="w-6 h-6 flex-shrink-0"/>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <button className="w-full mt-4 border border-lime-500 py-2 px-2 bg-lime-500 hover:bg-lime-600 hover:border-lime-600 focus:ring-4 focus:ring-opacity-50 focus:ring-lime-500 text-white disabled:opacity-50 disabled:cursor-not-allowed rounded-md">
                        Add to cart
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        );
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
    const inventory = await stripe.products.list();
    const paths = inventory.data.map((product) => ({
        params: { id: product.id },
    }));

    return {
        paths, 
        fallback: "blocking"
    };
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
    const inventory = await stripe.products.list({
        expand: ["data.default_price"],
    });
    const products = inventory.data.map((product) => {
        const price = product.default_price;
        return {
          currency: price.currency,
          id: product.id,
          name: product.name,
          price: price.unit_amount,
          image: product.images[0],
        };
    });
    const product = products.find((product) => product.id === params.id);

    return {
        props: {
            product,
        },
        revalidate: 60 * 60,
    };
}
```

I have looked at a few solutions suggesting to JSON.parse(JSON.stringify("string")). That did not work.

I Also got this back from blackbox but the function is already asynchronous, The `product` variable is still undefined when the `getStaticProps` function is called. This is because the `stripe.products.list()` function is asynchronous, and the `getStaticProps` function is synchronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's likely happening is that your `products.find` is not actually matching any products to your params.id. That results in `product` being undefined, and then NextJS doesn't like you having an undefined value in props.

A couple ways around this, depending on what you need:

1. Perhaps the most NextJS way of handing this, if product is not found, then return `notFound: true` instead of props, resulting in the 404 page

```
    if (!product) {
        return {
            notFound: true
        };
    }
```

2. Return a value other than undefined if product is not found:

```
    return {
        props: {
            product: product ?? null,
        },
        revalidate: 60 * 60,
    };
```

or, don't add the product prop at all unless it's defined

```
    return {
        props: {
            ...(product && { product }),
        },
        revalidate: 60 * 60,
    };
```

Only use #2 if your client is set up to handle the case where `product` is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like `products` might be nullish. [Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) could help here:

```
- const products = inventory.data.map((product) => {
+ const products = inventory?.data?.map((product) => {
```

Comment: I tried that solution and I am still getting the same serialization error.